# Reduce ANSIBLE task output

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible task that is used to remove deleted files from a static web folder.

```
- name: GUI - DELETE OLD STATIC DIRECTORY
  file:
    path="{{gui_dir}}/{{item.item.name}}/assets"
    state=absent
  when: (item.changed == true)
  with_items:
    - "{{gui_version.results}}"
  tags: ['check']
```

for each one of my front end apps, it produce the following output (even when skipped)

```
skipping: [uesg-3a-apps-qual] => (item={u'uid': 0, u'dest': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version', u'path': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version', u'owner': u'root', u'diff': {u'after': {u'path': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version'}, u'before': {u'path': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version'}}, u'size': 167, u'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'group': u'root', u'failed': False, u'checksum': u'6177a3255a58ee3e5489fde39db873b1abf2bc5d', u'changed': False, u'item': {u'version': u'1.0.7-SNAPSHOT', u'name': u'UES-GENESYS-ADMIN'}, u'state': u'file', u'gid': 0, u'mode': u'0644', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'directory_mode': None, u'force': False, u'remote_src': None, u'dest': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version', u'access_time': None, u'access_time_format': u'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S', u'_original_basename': u'GUI-VERSION.txt.j2', u'follow': False, u'owner': u'root', u'path': u'/data/web//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.version', u'src': None, u'group': u'root', u'modification_time': None, u'unsafe_writes': None, u'delimiter': None, u'regexp': None, u'seuser': None, u'recurse': False, u'serole': None, u'_diff_peek': None, u'content': None, u'state': u'file', u'mode': 420, u'modification_time_format': u'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S', u'selevel': None, u'attributes': None, u'backup': None, u'setype': None}}})
```

I would like to reduce the ouput of this task because it not very readable, is there a way of achieving my goal ?

Thanks

I tried to use the no_logs options but then it removes the logs completly and i would like to just have a cleaner and readable ouput

Comment: [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label), quote: "_When looping over complex data structures, the console output of your task can be enormous. To limit the displayed output, use the `label` directive with `loop_control`_".